# Inserting excel data into database

Tags: excel, laravel-5

I'm using [Maatwebsite laravel-excel](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/import) package to read my excel file.
And the code below shows how I'm trying to insert the data into my database.

First I *`post`* my file from my `view`:

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => route('teste'))) !!}
    {!! Form::file('filename')!!}
    {!! Form::submit('Importar') !!}                
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Then I use a `route` to redirect me to my `Controller`'s method:

```
public function importData(Request $request){

    Excel::load($request->input('filename'), function($reader) {
       $reader->ignoreEmpty();
       $results = $reader->get()->toArray();
       foreach($results as $key => $value){
          $turma = new import_temp;
          $turma->cod_disciplina = $value['cod_disciplina'];
          $turma->nome_disciplina = $value['nome_disciplina'];
          $turma->cod_turma = $value['cod_turma'];  
           //....
            }
        })->get();
    }
}
```

#### I have three questions:

**1)** Is there a cleaner/better way to pass the *name* of the file ? As that's all I need to read it;
**2)** As you can see by my `foreach`, I have to write every single field of my table with the `model` instance `$turma`. Is there a better way to insert this kind of data?
**3)** Also, my IDE gives me a warning about the way I'm assign the data: `model->field`:

> Referenced field is not found in subject class